# PPC Debian: eth0: switching to forced 10bt / 100bt

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ethernet

I recently installed debian on an old G4 iMac, and everything is working fine except that the console is constantly spammed with alternating

```
eth0: switching to forced 10bt
eth0: switching to forced 100bt
```

messages.  eth0 isn't configured at all in `/etc/network/interfaces`; I'm using the wireless interface on eth1 (which works fine).  `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` doesn't give any message; the alternating messages just keep coming.  Is there any way to get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try unloading the `sungem` kernel module (after `ifconfig eth0 down` to release the interface).

If that works you can blacklist it to avoid it being loaded on next reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a system with more than one ethernet port (say, a server such as a Netra), and unloading the sungem module is inappropriate, I found that I could silence the debug messages by forcing eth1 into 100mbps full duplex by running

```
ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full
```

and then plugging in a **loopback adaptor** into the spare ethernet port.
The results? Driver thinks theres a cable plugged in, then shuts up.